# ASP:GridView dynamic datasource from Querystring

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, sqldatasource, request.querystring

Just playing around with ASP.net C#. I am trying to pass a querystring to the gridview's datasource. The querystring is the SQLDataSource ID. This way one page can pull from different datasources based up on the querystring.

What am I doing wrong? 
**This can't be in the .cs file either.**

```
http://localhost/mypage.aspx?view=MyOtherDatasource
```

In above URL we would navigate to the mypage.aspx page, and the MyOtherDatasource would be selected.

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataSourceID='<% Request.QueryString["view"] %>'>
            <Columns>
               <asp:CommandField HeaderText="Actions" ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowEditButton="True" ShowHeader="True" />
            </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
```

My two datasources:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="MyDatasource1" runat="server" 
                            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:PDACConnectionString %>" 
                            SelectCommand="SQL STATEMENT HERE"
                            UpdateCommand="SQL STATEMENT HERE"
                            OnUpdated="OnUpdatedHandler">

</asp:SqlDataSource>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="MyOtherDatasource" runat="server" 
                            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:PDACConnectionString %>" 
                            SelectCommand="SQL STATEMENT HERE"
                            UpdateCommand="SQL STATEMENT HERE"
                            OnUpdated="OnUpdatedHandler">

</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: Do the datasources work when you manually have them in the code, without using the request.querystring ?

Comment: I'm a bit new to this still, but do you need "ToString()" tacked on the end?  ( Request.Querystring["view"].ToString() ) ... I typically do that type of coding in the code behind

Comment: "This can't be in the .cs file either." Why the artificial restriction? The code-behind file is the best place to do this sort of thing.

Comment: Part of the challenge.

Comment: Well, you can either put the code in the `.aspx` file inside a `<script runat="server">...</script>` block, or use [a custom `ExpressionBuilder` class](http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/The-CodeExpressionBuilder) to insert a small code expression inline.

Answer (score 0):

How about setting it up in code behind:

```
GridView1.DataSourceID = Request.QueryString["view"];
```

It worked fine for me.